# Get day of week from current date and specifying first day of week

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vb6, .net-3.5, dayofweek

I am migrating a legacy VB6 project into C#.

I want to obtain the equivalent in C# from expression below:

```
Weekday(Date, vbMonday)
```

I know there is a function in C#:

```
int dayOfWeek = (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
```

but how to specify that the first day of the week  is Monday and then function DayOfWeek take it into account and return the correct value?

I need to obtain an int value.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're aiming to achieve. The `DayOfWeek` property returns a `DayOfWeek` enum value - that's unaffected by which is the first day of the week. What values are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the first day of the week by calling `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek`, but I think you can do without that.

The `Weekday` function returns 1 for Monday, just like `DayOfWeek`. The only special case is Sunday, which .NET returns as `0`, while VB returns 7.

Just do the math:

```
int dayOfWeek = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday
                 ? 7
                 : (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: Are you sure? From msdn documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh(v=vs.90).aspx sunday in vb6 is 1, monday 2 and saturday 7 if you don't specify first day of week as parameter in WeekDay function, by default first day of week is sunday. In my example, you specify first day of week to be Monday by specifying it by argument in WeekDay function, so Monday is 1, Tuesday is 2, and Sunday is 7, this is how I understand.

Comment: Yes, but you set it to be `Monday = 1`, that is why it is 1 (so you deviate from the documentation).

Comment: ok, so as in .NET you do not specify first day of the week, it is set by default to sunday, so sunday is 0 and monday is 1, tuesday 2,..., saturday 6.

Comment: The enum is. I don't use the actual first day of the week from the culture since you don't need that to do the math.

Comment: And in vb6, using WeekDay(Date,vbMonday), if Monday is specified as first day of the week why Monday gets 1 and not 0?

Comment: Because VB dislikes 0. In this case it also has a different meaning (read the docs).

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2008, 6, 11);



Console.WriteLine((int) dateValue.DayOfWeek);
```

// The example displays the following output:
//       3

```
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("dddd"));
```

// The example displays the following output:
 //       Wed

```
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("dddd"));
```

// The example displays the following output:
//       Wednesday